# Determine the seed of C# Random Instance

Tags: c#, random, prediction

Out of interest, I am playing around with the Random class that comes with C#. I am trying to predict the future. As it is pseudo random, there must be some way to predict the numbers. The only way I can think of so far is brute force (Getting all possible seeds and finding the pattern of the random numbers in them) but I believe it will be too much processing power as the seed can be anything from -2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647.

So far I have determined that:

```
new Random() == new Random(Environment.TickCount)
```

and that both these classes will provide the same random numbers in the same order.

Is it in any way possible to determine the seed of the Random class instance? If you could know the Environment.TickCount when the Random class was instantiated, the random numbers could be predicted, but I have no idea whether it could be done.

Comment: You might find [this article](http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/02/producing-permutations-part-six/) and [this sequel](http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/06/producing-permutations-part-seven/) by Eric Lippert interesting.  He challenged users to predict the future much in the way you are doing.  Brute forcing the seed is faster than you'd think, especially given that certain `Environment.TickCount` values are more likely.

Comment: Thanks Brian! Very interesting!! I wen't ahead yesterday and tried the brute force. You're right, its VERY fast. I matched up a sequence of 15 numbers, and I found the seed number in 22.3 seconds on average when searching through 10 000 000 seeds. This result is from a pretty standard dual core laptop. The article is very interesting, I haven't even though about the fact that some seed values are more likely than others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As it is pseudo random, there must be some way to predict the numbers.

Indeed; if you know the internal state (in particular `inext`,`inextp` and `SeedArray` - so 58 `int` values in total), **and** you know the exact operations that are going to be requested in the exact order (for example, asking for `Next()`, `Next()`, `NextBytes()` is very different to asking for `Next()`, `NextBytes()`, `Next()`) - then you could make entirely accurate forward guesses. That is the entire *point* of a seeded PRNG - it allows for repeatable randomness, which is useful in many scenarios when you need to be able to replay events.

So: I don't think you could ever get back the original *seed*, but to predict the *future* (rather than the past) you don't need the seed - you just need 58 `int` values.

However! Anything where the randomness *matters* should be using the *cryptographic* random providers - and those are *not* repeatable or guessable.

For example:

```
static class Program {
    static Random Clone(this Random source)
    {
        var clone = new Random();
        var type = typeof(Random);
        var field = type.GetField("inext",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        field.SetValue(clone, field.GetValue(source));
        field = type.GetField("inextp",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        field.SetValue(clone, field.GetValue(source));
        field = type.GetField("SeedArray",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        int[] arr = (int[])field.GetValue(source);
        field.SetValue(clone, arr.Clone());
        return clone;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        var clone = rand.Clone();
        Console.WriteLine("My predictions:");
        Console.WriteLine(clone.Next());
        Console.WriteLine(clone.Next());
        Console.WriteLine(clone.Next());
        Console.WriteLine("Actual:");
        Console.WriteLine(rand.Next());
        Console.WriteLine(rand.Next());
        Console.WriteLine(rand.Next());
    }
}
```

Comment: That's really cool! :) Just a minor nitpick: `NextDouble` or `Next` really isn't that different. `NextDouble()` is equivalent to `Next() / (double)Int32.MaxValue`. But more importantly, it doesn't influence the numbers that follow, i.e. `Next, NextDouble, Next` and `Next, Next, Next` will create the same numbers at positions 1 and 3.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth fair enough; I didn't even look at how `NextDouble()` is implemented; perhaps `NextBytes()` is a better example for that. The point I was trying to make was that the number of samples taken is important. I stupidly assumed `NextDouble`, being 64-bit, used 2 samples. This is not in fact the case. However, `NextBytes` uses `buffer.Length` samples, so substitute `NextBytes` in place of `NextDouble`, where the `buffer.Length` is not `1`, and that is what I was trying to say.

Comment: Wow! That's pretty awesome! And yes, while it is true cryptographic randomizers SHOULD be used in the case of important random numbers, many programmers won't go to the trouble.

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of `Random` doesn't store the seed anywhere - it uses a seed array instead. So unfortunately there's no way to determine the seed.

The constructor for Random which takes a seed looks like this:

```
public Random(int Seed)
{
    this.SeedArray = new int[0x38];
    int num4 = (Seed == 0x80000000) ? 0x7fffffff : Math.Abs(Seed);
    int num2 = 0x9a4ec86 - num4;
    this.SeedArray[0x37] = num2;
    int num3 = 0x1;
    for (int i = 0x1; i < 0x37; i++)
    {
        int index = (0x15 * i) % 0x37;
        this.SeedArray[index] = num3;
        num3 = num2 - num3;
        if (num3 < 0x0)
        {
            num3 += 0x7fffffff;
        }
        num2 = this.SeedArray[index];
    }
    for (int j = 0x1; j < 0x5; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0x1; k < 0x38; k++)
        {
            this.SeedArray[k] -= this.SeedArray[0x1 + ((k + 0x1e) % 0x37)];
            if (this.SeedArray[k] < 0x0)
            {
                this.SeedArray[k] += 0x7fffffff;
            }
        }
    }
    this.inext = 0x0;
    this.inextp = 0x15;
    Seed = 0x1;
}
```

You can see that it doesn't store the seed anywhere.

(An odd thing about this is that it assigns 1 to the Seed variable right at the end for some strange reason - but that's not really relevant; it's just a bit weird.)

You could write your own wrapper class for `Random` which retains the seed value for later retrieval. The implementation would just remember `Seed`:

```
public class MyRandom: Random
{
    public MyRandom() : this(Environment.TickCount)
    {
    }

    public MyRandom(int seed) : base(seed)
    {
        this.seed = seed;
    }

    public int Seed
    {
        get { return seed; }
    }

    private readonly int seed;
}
```

Comment: I presume Seed is set to 1 to reduce the length of time the value is stored in memory, reducing the opportunities for someone to extract it.

Comment: @Tobsey if it *mattered* that `seed` was available, then it would be entirely inappropriate to be using `Random` IMO - that would be a scenario where you should use the cryptographic random providers

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree, doesn't mean that everyone that should be using a crypto provider is though! I've no idea why it was written to change the seed variable, it was just my best guess.